# why getString functions in api scilab giving errors?

Tags: linux, scilab

All the getString functions mentioned in this document are giving errors.
I have even tried the example code given on this link which also not working
`https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.2/en_US/api_string.html`
I am getting following error:

```
exec: error on line #21: "addinter: problem with one of the entry point."

I am using scilab 6.1.0 , Ubuntu 18.04
```

here is my code

```
#include<Scierror.h>
#include<api_scilab.h>
#include "dlib.h"
#include <ctype.h>

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C"
{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "localization.h"
#include "api_scilab.h"
#include "Scierror.h"
#include "localization.h"
#include "sciprint.h"
#include "sci_malloc.h"
#include "api_string.h"

static const char fname[] = "xml_parser";
int sci_xml_parser(scilabEnv env, int nin, scilabVar* in, int nopt, scilabOpt* opt, int nout, scilabVar* out)
    {
        double* in1 = new double[104];
        double* out1 = NULL;   
        double* size = NULL;
        wchar_t* xml_file = new wchar_t[100];
        wchar_t** output_file =NULL;
        if (nin != 2)
        {
        Scierror(77, _("%s: Wrong number of input argument(s): %d expected.\n"), fname, 2);
        return 1;
        }

        int *k =  scilab_createString(env, xml_file);
        scilab_getString(env, in[0], &xml_file);
        out[0] = scilab_createDoubleMatrix2d(env, 1, 1, 0);
        scilab_getDoubleArray(env, out[0], &out1);
        out1[0] = 0;
    return STATUS_OK;
    }
}
```

This is the output of gcc -v command

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Building interfaces with Scilab 6.1.0 needs a c++17 compiler. What is you version of gcc/g++ ?

Comment: I am using c++14, and I do not get above error while compiling for the first time after i load scilab. So, I have to every time close the software and open it again for compilation.

Comment: Please type the following on the command line and give me the output : `gcc -v`